# authentication token cache for azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We use an Identity server to issue tokens for 3rd party service we use.

Each token have TTL of 1 hour.
Wanted to know what is the best practice for caching this token when consuming it from an azure function.
I know that function should be stateless but it's makes no sense to ask for a new token in every function run.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here a few options, in increasing order of effort

1. Use a static member to store the token in memory, and lazily do the authentication process when necessary. There are absolutely no guarantees about how often this will save you the authentication step - it will vary wildly depending on how often your function is running, on how many different machines, etc.
2. Make use of the temporary filesystem storage provided to functions. You can read/write files on %TEMP%.
3. Use a persistent external store such as a database, redis cache, etc.

Please note that I'm listing these options without considering whether you have additional security requirements regarding the persistence of the token.

Comment: right now I'm doing number 1 , will consider checking number 2 .
option #3 is problematic due to both security and SLA.

Comment: Assume that the first two will only work if the deployment model is App Service Plan. Consumption Plan shouldn't guarantee reuse of server assets.

Comment: @Josh they both work in the consumption plan too. You will likely get more cache misses than you would if you were in an app service plan but this scenario is just about optimistically caching the token so it doesn't matter.