# Does Azure Functions on Consumption Plan utilize multiple servers?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

When I run an Azure Function App on the Consumption Plan, does it then utilize multiple servers, or does every instance of the functions always run on the same server?

**Access Tokens**
The background for the question is that I want to cache the access tokens for APIs that the functions are using. Right now I refresh the tokens when the initial timer triggered function starts - but it's no real solution.

Each function should try using the existing auth token and then ask for a new one if it fails. Similar question here: [authentication token cache for azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474027/authentication-token-cache-for-azure-function) with a comment saying the [Consumption plan doesn't quarantee reuse of servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474027/authentication-token-cache-for-azure-function#comment80015166_43481064)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does utilise multiple servers, so in-memory caching will end up having multiple cache instances. The filesystem is shared across servers though, so disk-based caching is an option, or you can just go for a distributed cache like Azure Cache for Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We end up using Redis Cache to handle the same scenario.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer

Comment: nevermind, I am new and learning to share and ans based on my exp :)